# In Quanteda, how can we match quotation marks literally?

Tags: r, regex, quanteda, quotation-marks

Brief question as I'm trying to match quotation marks in a sentence token using Quanteda's `tokens_lookup()` function and `valuetype="regex"`. Based on the information provided [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/stringi-search-regex.html) on the regex flavor Quanteda uses, I thought the way to go with would be `\Q ... \E`, but that didn't do the trick.

```
library(quanteda) 
# package version: 1.5.2

text <- c("text „some quoted text“ more text", "text « some quoted text » more text")

dict <- dictionary(list(MY_KEY = c("\Q*\E")))
# Error: '\Q' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\Q"
```

I also tried to match the quotation mark directly `"“"` which at least seems to be a legal regex pattern, but in the end that didn't work either. Nor did variations of `\Q...\E` with double backslashes as they are used for word boundaries for instance (`\\b`).

So the more general question I believe is whether the regular expressions mentioned [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/stringi-search-regex.html) are compatible with what Quanteda understands as `valuetype="regex"`.

**EDIT:**

This worked for the first string, yet not for the second.

```
dict <- dictionary(list(MY_KEY = c(".\".")))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "match" quotation marks? Do you want to select all tokens that are a form of quotation mark? (The default quanteda tokenizer will make your quotation variants into separate tokens.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions in **quanteda** are built on the **stringi** package, which supports Unicode character categories.  You can retrieve all of your quotes by using these categories in a search pattern:

- [Ps](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ps/index.htm), [Pe](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pe/index.htm) - punctuation, open and close
- [Pi](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ps/index.htm), [Pf](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/f/index.htm) - Punctuation initial and final quote

I included all four, since for example `„` is in Ps but not Pi, and `«` is in Pi but not Ps.

Further details are [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pi/index.htm).

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.1

text <- c(
  "text „some quoted text“ more text",
  "text « some quoted text » more text"
)
toks <- tokens(text)

tokens_select(toks, "[\\p{Pf}\\p{Pi}\\p{Ps}\\p{Pe}]", valuetype = "regex")
## Tokens consisting of 2 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "„"
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "«" "»"
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, that's incredibly helpful! ... I am using `what="sentence"` which makes this a bit trickier and also my idea was to define a pattern that allows me to match any sentence containing a specific word on the condition that this word has NO quotation marks around it. Say I'd like to match "I like apples a lot" but not "I like "apples" a lot". Thought that might work with `\\P{}` instead of `\\p{}` but so far it didn't.

Comment: To provide some context: `text<-c("xxx apple xxx","xxx „apple“ xxx")` ... `tokens(text, what="sentence") %>% ("apple[\\P{Pf}\\P{Pi}\\P{Ps}\\P{Pe}]", valuetype = "regex")` Expectation: match / no match. Reality: match / match.

Comment: That's really not part of the original question, but I could demonstrate how to answer that if you specify a clear new question with the details you are looking for and an expected result. Be sure to specify if you are looking for a set of sentences with the match/no match, or whether you want to identify quoted or non-quoted target terms (as terms, not sentences).

Comment: Right, thanks. I was already thinking about asking a new question. My idea behind this one right here was that it would easily allow me to solve the problem if I knew how to identify characters like quotation marks. Seems that this is not the case, so I'll formulate a new one right away. On the match sentences vs. identify target terms: I'm trying to "match" any sentence containing a specific target term, but not if the target term is put into quotation marks. So that would be the condition for the match / no match.

Comment: Oh never mind, I figured it out. Do you think I should still ask the question and answer it myself? I doubt that that would be relevant to others, since it's mostly just about the use of `[^...]`. Still, I'm wondering why some of the `stringi` RegExes don't work the way they should such as `[\\P{...}\\P{...}]` with capital letter `P` which should equal `[^\\p{...}\\p{...}]` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible it is a language or locale issue?  Your "quotation marks" don't look like quotation marks on my screen and when I change the pattern I can find them.

```r
library(quanteda) 
#> Package version: 2.0.1

text <- c("text „some quoted text“ more text", "text « some quoted text » more text")

dict <- dictionary(list(found_it = c("„"), found_other = c("«")))

toks2 <- tokens(text)
tokens_lookup(toks2, dict)

#> Tokens consisting of 2 documents.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "found_it"
#> 
#> text2 :
#> [1] "found_other"
```

Comment: I just found out it has something to do with the `what="sentence"` which doesn't allow me to match the quotation mark but which I would really like to keep. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Second, I am still wondering if there is a universal regex for matching any quotation mark, no matter the style of the quotation mark, like `\Q...\E` (which, as I said, doesn't work).

Comment: It's very unlikely there is a "universal" regex for all "styles" of quotation marks.  Almost by definition if you are tokenizing at the sentence level `what = "sentence"` you shouldn't expect `tokens_lookup` to find quotation marks as separate tokens.  If `toks2` is tokenized at sentence level then you can use `grepl("«" ,toks2)` to find all the sentences that have that character in it.

Comment: Well it does work if I search for `c(".\".")`, even with `what="sentence"`, at least for the first string that is. And on the universal thing: I read the description of `\Q...\E` to be a universal pattern for quoted strings. The catch is just that I get an error message saying that this is not a legal regex but other than that... ;-)